# Titanium Appcelerator custom android MainActivity

Tags: java, android, titanium, android-manifest, splash-screen

The idea is to replace the default splash screen in Titanium with a native one in android.

I created the SplashActivity.java and placed it in the 
`"Platform->android->src->com->example->app"`

Then created the custom `AndroidManifest.xml` in `"Platform->android"`

The app is launching the `SplashActivity` as the main one but am stuck at opening the Titanium Activity after finishing from the splash screen.

Is there any way to open the main Titanium Activity from a custom activity?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The *TestApp* is your app name.

I solved it by editing the custom **AndroidManifest.xml** and adding the **TestAppActivity** as activity.

And in the `SplashActivity.java` added:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,TestAppActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Comment: this solution don't replace splashscreen startActivity open titanium splash screen

Comment: This solution was in 2015 - of course there are many other solutions by now :) No need for negative vote.